# What are you being interviewed for when you sit a teaching interview?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I had a disagreement with a friend over this question.

Which choice is the right one?

> I have an interview for a teaching _____ at the university.

- skill,
- profession,
- career,
- post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post is correct.

**Skill**

Is something you will need to possess in order to secure the post.

**Profession**

Is something you establish yourself, owing to the nature of jobs you gain skill at, apply for and are successful at winning.

**Career**

Likewise a career is something you build yourself, an interviewer can not award you a career, although they may be able to offer you a career *opportunity*. You still need to *build* the career yourself, by the degree to which you are successful at your job, and the career *moves* you make (if any).

**Post**

Refers to a single job *posting* and this is what you are being interviewed for when you sit a job interview.

Comment: _position_ is also a possibility.